# How can I convert the Int given by GetPixel of Android.Graphics to a Color?

Tags: c#, android, bitmap, xamarin.android

I want to get the Color of a pixel in a Bitmap. For that normally I use GetPixel(x,y). But with Android.Graphics that method gives me an int representing the Color. So I need to know how can I get this Color from that integer.

In fact that is what I want to do finaly (a white removal in the mPlan):

```
for (int x=0; x <  PlanWidth; x++)
{
    for (int y=0; y <  PlanHeight; y++)
    {
        if (mPlan.GetPixel(x, y) ==  Color.White)                    
            mPlan.SetPixel(x, y, (Color.White - mPlan.GetPixel(x, y)));
    }
}
```

Comment: Is something wrong with the current code? In java it will be completely correct, because `Color.White` is int

Comment: What do you mean by "a white removal" ? Do you want to remove each white pixel from your bitmap? Or do you just want to darken each pixel ?

Comment: Which color are you using? ie system.drawing.color, windows.media.color .

Comment: `Color.White.ToArgb()`? You can convert Color.White to int instead of each GetPixel() result

Comment: @MikeT I am working with Xamarin/Android and the color is given by Android.Graphics

Comment: thought so but always worth making sure

Comment: @SergeyGlotov I tried that but the integer given by GetPixel(x,y) is not an Argb So I can not recover the resuting color then to set it in the pixel

Comment: What returns GetPixel() if not an ARGB? I'm looking in the docs and it says "the returned color is a non-premultiplied ARGB value."

Comment: @Sergey Clotov That is what I am trying to undestand

Comment: @dou, so, at least for me, the question is really not clear. What `Color.White - mPlan.GetPixel(x, y)` is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Android.Graphics.Color](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/Android.Graphics.Color/) has constructor `Color(Int32)`. To convert int to `Color` you can do something like this:

```
new Color(mPlan.GetPixel(x, y)) ==  Color.White
```

but I think will be better to convert `Color.White` to int using `Color.White.ToArgb()` and replace `SetPixel()` argument by `Color.Black` because `Color.White - Color.White` will be `Color.Black`.

```
int white = Color.White.ToArgb();
for (int x=0; x < PlanWidth; x++)
{
    for (int y=0; y < PlanHeight; y++)
    {
        if (mPlan.GetPixel(x, y) ==  white)                    
            mPlan.SetPixel(x, y, Color.Black);
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes but SetPixel Takes a Color as a third parametre not an int. I dont know how to recover the color then.
 Color.FromArgb won't work.

Comment: @dou You're doing unneeded calculations. GetPixel() returned White inside the if condition, you know this from the condition itself. So you don't need to subtract Color.White from Color.White, you can replace it with Color.Black

Comment: @dou Will it work? `mPlan.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(white - mPlan.getPixel(x, y)) `

Comment: It works thanks.  `Plan.SetPixel(x, y, new Color(white - mPlan.getPixel(x, y))  `

Comment: I would really like to know, what the `if` part is supposed to do. If the color is white, and you substract white from white, you get black. Or not? :)

Comment: I don't know :) @dou should know why he needs it.

Answer (score 1):

To cast your int color to RGB color in xamarinC# for android you just have to do this :

```
Color myColor = new Color(yourBitmap.GetPixel(x,y);
```

Then you can work with it's components like this :

```
 byte myColorRedValue = myColor.R;
 byte myColorBlueValue = myColor.B;
 byte myColorGreenValue = myColor.G;
 byte myColorAlphaValue = myColor.A;
```

So for example if you want to darken your color just do this :

```
 myColor.R = (byte)(myColor.R / 2);
 myColor.G = (byte)(myColor.G / 2);
 myColor.B = (byte)(myColor.B / 2);
```

This will give you three int between 0 and 255. To darken your color you just have to substract them with some number (obviously you have to check if your results are superiors or equals to zero).

This is the easiest way to achieve what you want and to understand how it works from a beginner perspective

Comment: I tried that also but I cannot use Color.red as a method

Comment: OP uses C#, not Java

Comment: Wouldn't it then be `Color.Red = myColor`?

Comment: @Mars `Color.Red` is constant for red color. I guess it will be `myColor.R`, `myColor.G`, `myColor.B`

Comment: I'm very sorry, i forgot about C# as it is not in the title. I'm working currently with xamarin android, i will give you the answer in few minutes

Comment: Oh. Silly me. But myColor is an int, so .R .G and .B won't apply here either, right? They are properties from Color structure.

Comment: @Mars Silly me now :) Yes, it is int, they won't apply

Comment: Damn, too late :-)